# Mpi_Send and Mpi_Recv to send partitions of a matrix instead of scattering

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to send partitions of a NxN matrix to different process.. I succed in this using MPI_Scatterv, as you can seen in the code below, but if I try to use instead MPI_Send and MPI_Recv the result is a segfault. Why?
I saw different similar questions to this, like this one [MPI Matrix Multiplication with Dynamic Allocation: Seg. Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866723/mpi-matrix-multiplication-with-dynamic-allocation-seg-fault), but nothing changes...

```
n = N/nprocs;   
n0 = n + N - n*nprocs;
int counts[nprocs], displs[nprocs];
counts[0] = n0*N;
displs[0] = 0;
for(i=1;i<nprocs;i++){
    counts[i]=n*N;
    displs[i]=(n0+(i-1)*n)*N;
}       
double * weights = (double *)calloc(N*N, (sizeof(double)));
if(myid == 0){
    n = n0;      
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=i; j<N; j++){
            if(i==j) *(weights+i*N+j) = 0;
            else {
               *(weights+i*N+j) = rand() / (RAND_MAX+1.0);
               *(weights+j*N+i) = *(weights+i*N+j);
            }
        }
    }
} 
double * partition = (double *)calloc(n*N, (sizeof(double)));
MPI_Scatterv(weights, counts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, partition, n*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, COMM);
```

Instead, using the send and recv primitives:

```
if(myid==0){
    for(i=0; i<nprocs; i++)
        MPI_Send(weights+displs[i], counts[i], MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, COMM); 
}
MPI_Recv(partition, counts[myid], MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, COMM, status);
```

What is wrong? Thank you in advance...
p.s.: sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

It's a very minor problem; although I don't see the variable definition, I strongly suspect the MPI_Recv line should be `MPI_Recv(..., COMM, &status)`.

There is one more issue, however; a task should avoid sending messages to itself, and it *must* not issue a *blocking* send (eg, `MPI_Send` vs. `MPI_Isend`) to itself; for large enough messages, that send will deadlock, task 0 is issuing a blocking send but not actively receiving it yet.

Something like this would work:

```
if(myid==0){
    for(i=1; i<nprocs; i++)
        MPI_Send(weights+displs[i], counts[i], MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, COMM);

    memcpy(weights+displs[0], partition, counts[0]*sizeof(double));
} else {
    MPI_Recv(partition, counts[myid], MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, COMM, &status);
}
```

Note that as a practical matter, `MPI_Scatterv` should be as fast or faster than a loop over sends.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately nothing changes... The status variable is a pointer so this is not the problem, and even if task 0 doesn't send and receive anything I have a segfault.
I think that the problem is in my pointer buffer (weights or partition) in the send or receive primitive.
I know that MPI_Scatterv is faster but I encountered an error message on it if I try to use it on different version of OpenMpi.
May you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'status is a pointer'?   Do you have `MPI_Status *status;`?  If so that won't work, it's a pointer to nowhere.  You'll need to either `status = malloc(sizeof(MPI_Status));`, or do `MPI_Status status;` and as above.