# Segmentation Error - Matrix Multiplication in C using MPI Send/Recv

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I'm doing some matrix multiplication in C with MPI.

In which my test matrix is of the format :

**A(i,j) = 2i + j**

**B(i,j) = i + 3j**

I want to use MPI_Bcast to Broadcast Matrix A to all the ranks, and use MPI_Send, RECV for Matrix B and calculating the Result Matrix.

From what I've noticed the error seems to be something in between recombining the results because MPI Send and Receive for the master threads is working fine but instantly produces a seg fault 11 afterwards.

I previously was trying to broadcast A matrix and send B matrix but that did not work because of seg faults as well. Now I try to send them both using MPI_Send and get the following error. It says that an error occurred in MPI_Send tho I have checked everything and can't figure it out. I added printf lines in many places in my code to know till where it reaches. It reaches till 
`printf("%d\n", a[0][0]);`
and then stops.

In reference to my comment, I changed the way I do allocMatrix.

**UPDATED CODE :**

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Matrix A's x and y dimensions
#define aX 3
#define aY 2

//Matrix A's i and j values
#define aI 2
#define aJ 1

//Matrix B's x and y dimensions
#define bX 2
#define bY 2

//MatrixB's i and j values
#define bI 1
#define bJ 3


int** allocMatrix(int sizeX, int sizeY);
int** createMatrix(int sizeX, int sizeY, int i, int j);
void printMatrix(int** matrix, int sizeX, int sizeY);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Status stat;
    int rank, numranks;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numranks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);


    int** a = allocMatrix(aX, aY);
    int** b;
    if (rank == 0) {
        a = createMatrix(aX, aY, aI, aJ);
        b = createMatrix(bX, bY, bI, bJ);
    }
//  MPI_Bcast(&a, aX * aY, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

/*  int** bSub;
    int *counts = (int *) malloc(bY * sizeof(int));
    int *displacements = (int *) malloc(bY * sizeOf(int));
    int offset = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < bY; y++){
        displacements[i] = offset;
        offset += b[y]
    }
    MPI_Scatterv(b, bX * bY, MPI_INT, bSub,  
*/

    if (rank == 0){
        int rowCount = bY / (numranks - 1);
        int displacement = 0;
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i < numranks; i++){
            int** resultSub;
            printf("Recieved from rank %d\n", i);

            MPI_Recv(&displacement, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
            MPI_Recv(&rowCount, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
            MPI_Recv(&resultSub, rowCount * bX, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
            for(y = displacement; y < displacement + rowCount; y++){
                for(x = 0; x < bX; x++){
                    result[y][x] = resultSub[y - displacement][x];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Result:\n");

        for(y = 0; y < aY; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < bX; x++){
                printf("%d ", result[y][x]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    } else {
        int displacement;
        int rowCount;
        printf("Rank %d:\n", rank);
        MPI_Recv(&a, aX* aY, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
        printf("Rank %d got a\n", rank);
        printf("%d\n", a[0][0]);
        MPI_Recv(&displacement, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
        printf("Rank %d received displacement\n", rank);
        MPI_Recv(&rowCount, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
        int** bSub = allocMatrix(aX,rowCount);
        printf("Rank %d received rowCount\n", rank);
        MPI_Recv(&bSub, rowCount * bX, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
        printf("Rank %d received bSub\n", rank);
        int** result = allocMatrix(bX, rowCount);
        int x, y, j;
        printf("Rank %d starting\n", rank);
        for(y = 0; y < rowCount; y++){
            for(x = 0; x < aX; x++){
                int sum = 0;
                printf("Rank %d X: %d, Y: %d\n", rank, x, y);
                 for(j = 0; j < bX; j++){
                    printf("Rank %d J: %d\n", rank, j);
                    sum += a[j][x] * bSub[y][j];
                }
                result[y][x] = sum;     
            }
        }
        printf("Rank %d ending\n", rank);
        MPI_Send(&displacement, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rowCount, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&result, bX * rowCount, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
//  printMatrix(a, aX, aY);
//  printMatrix(b, bX, bY); 
    MPI_Finalize();
}

int** allocMatrix(int sizeX, int sizeY){
    /*int** matrix = malloc(sizeY * sizeof(*matrix));
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y < sizeY; y++){
        matrix[y] = malloc(sizeX * sizeof(*matrix[y]));
    }
    return matrix;*/
    int *data = (int *)malloc(sizeX * sizeY * sizeof(int));
    int **matrix =(int **)malloc(sizeY * sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++){
        matrix[i] = &(data[sizeX * i]);
    }
int** createMatrix(int sizeX, int sizeY, int i, int j){
    int** matrix = allocMatrix(sizeX, sizeY);
    int x, y;
    for(y = 0; y < sizeY; y++){
        for(x = 0; x < sizeX; x++){
            matrix[y][x] = i * x + j * y;
        }
    }   
    return matrix;
}

void printMatrix(int** matrix, int sizeX, int sizeY){
        int x, y;
    for(y = 0; y < sizeY; y++){
                for(x = 0; x < sizeX; x++){
                        printf("%d ", matrix[y][x]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

The error I receive now :

```
Rank 15:
Rank 1:
Rank 7:
Rank 13:
Rank 16:
Rank 4:
Rank 2:
Rank 8:
Rank 17:
Rank 10:
Rank 6:
Rank 11:
Rank 5:
Rank 12:
Rank 9:
Rank 14:
[zarya:46623] *** Process received signal ***
[zarya:46623] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[zarya:46623] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[zarya:46623] Failing at address: 0x200000000
Rank 3:
Rank 1 got a
[zarya:46623] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7ff4f72bf390]
[zarya:46623] [ 1] ./mm.cx[0x400f1c]
[zarya:46623] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ff4f6f04830]
[zarya:46623] [ 3] ./mm.cx[0x400979]
[zarya:46623] *** End of error message ***
[winston:06305] *** Process received signal ***
[winston:06305] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[winston:06305] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[winston:06305] Failing at address: 0x200000000
Rank 2 got a
[winston:06305] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fe4536d1390]
[winston:06305] [ 1] ./mm.cx[0x400f1c]
[winston:06305] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fe453316830]
[winston:06305] [ 3] ./mm.cx[0x400979]
[winston:06305] *** End of error message ***
[roadhog:16798] *** Process received signal ***
[roadhog:16798] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[roadhog:16798] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[roadhog:16798] Failing at address: 0x200000000
Rank 3 got a
[roadhog:16798] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f7216429390]
[roadhog:16798] [ 1] ./mm.cx[0x400f1c]
[roadhog:16798] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f721606e830]
[roadhog:16798] [ 3] ./mm.cx[0x400979]
[roadhog:16798] *** End of error message ***
[orisa:32932] *** Process received signal ***
[orisa:32932] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[orisa:32932] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[orisa:32932] Failing at address: 0x200000000
Rank 4 got a
[orisa:32932] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f18ce4d7390]
[orisa:32932] [ 1] ./mm.cx[0x400f1c]
[orisa:32932] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f18ce11c830]
[orisa:32932] [ 3] ./mm.cx[0x400979]
[orisa:32932] *** End of error message ***
[hanzo:43879] *** Process received signal ***
```

some more random garbage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866723/mpi-matrix-multiplication-with-dynamic-allocation-seg-fault?rq=1 I feel like this could be somewhat related to my problem. If there is an issue with the way I am allocating the arrays.

Comment: I changed my code in accordance to that link and still have a seg fault.

Comment: It looks like `bSub` is never allocated

Comment: Hi thanks ptb I edited the code, its working a bit better however I still get the sig fault. I updated the code to reflect the changes.

Comment: I feel like something must be wrong with sending or receiving matrix A because they all say their rank, but then have seg fault right after..

Comment: In order to broadcast the matrix, you have to `MPI_Bcast(a[0], ...)`. Please write a [MCVE] and keep it clean and simple with one issue at a time.

Comment: As an aside, variable length arrays would go a long way towards simplifying this.